# BIKE: Bit Flipping Key Encapsulation - Inverse encryption / decryption

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm trying to understand white paper about [BIKE Asymmetric crypt](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01671903/document).
And actually read about the inverse matrix that needs to be produced for decryption.

My concern is:
Can I actually encrypt data with **private key** and decrypt with **public key** instead too?

If so, there are 3 Versions of BIKE: "BIKE-1, BIKE-2, BIKE-3"

Which one will work?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, what are you intending to achieve with that?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure, but I don't think that will work for the following simple reason:

The secret key in BIKE is a sparse parity check matrix of an MDPC code $(h_0, h_1)$, and the public key is always dense.

The decryption of BIKE (in all versions) relies upon the sparsity of the parity check matrix of the secret key. If you were to swap the keys the bit-flipping decoder wouldn't work anymore - it's decoding failure rate increases linearly with the weight of the parity check matrix.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

> encrypt data with **private key**

Uggh, BIKE is never supposed to be a digital signature scheme! That RSA-day misnomer should stop!